# Angular auth guard being applied on wrong route

Tags: angular, typescript

So I dont want users to view some pages if they are not logged in. So I am using auth guard and if they try to access a path without being loged in they will be redirected to the login page.

Following is my **auth.guard.ts**:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NeedAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {


    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      return true;
    }
    console.log('about to redirect to login -- inside auth guard');
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);

    return false;
  }

}
```

Following is my **app-routing.module.ts**:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {
   path: '', component: SiteLayoutComponent,
   children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: LandingPageComponent},
    { path: 'pricing', component: PricingComponent},
    { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent},
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
   ]
 },
 {
  path: '', component: AppLayoutComponent,
  children: [
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [NeedAuthGuard]} --> Only applied to dashboard
  ]
 }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

So my problem is, When it try to access my signup page (/signup) I am being redirected to the login page and I am not able to figure out why. Following is my signup page:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private apiService: ApiService, private router: Router) {
    this.user = new User();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
   if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
   }
  }

  signup() {
    console.log('signup button clicked', this.user.email,  this.user.fullname, this.user.password);
    this.apiService.signup(this.user.email, this.user.fullname, this.user.password)
     .subscribe( response => {
        if(response.token) {
          this.authService.saveToken(response.token);
          console.log('signup - token saved');
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
        }
     }, response => {
          console.log(response.error.message);
     });
  }

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you soo much.

Comment: Can you please provide stackblitz with mock services for implementing same scenario?

Comment: You need to add the '/dashboard' because the empty route is used 2 times.

Comment: @NicuVlad tried it but its not working

Comment: Interesting, when you remove the AuthGuard. Does this work correctly when you navigate to /dashboard and /signup?

Comment: Can you put a log in the `ngOnInit` in the SignupComponent to see what is in your isLoggedIn. It is possible that you are redirected to /dashboard and then redirected to login.

Comment: `if (this.authService.isLoggedIn)` in the SignupComponetn should be `if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) ` --> note the `()` after isLoggedIn

Comment: @SumanthJois I made the comment an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if (this.authService.isLoggedIn)` in the SignupComponent should be

`if (this.authService.isLoggedIn())` --> note the `()` after isLoggedIn

otherwise you only check if there is a function called `isLoggedIn` in the auth.service